# JTable: waiting for row to be selected according user input

Tags: java, swing, jtable, joptionpane, listselectionlistener

I have a `JTable` (master) to which I added a `ListSelectionListener` to catch when a row is selected and populate another `JTable` (detail) according the selected row.
Now some requirements have changed and if come conditions are met, when the user clicks into another row, I should show a `JOptionPane` with YES/NO options, and only if YES is clicked then the new row can be selected.
How can I achieve this? Shall I use always `ListSelectionListener`? I don't think so as it is raised only after the selection is done.

Answer (score 1):

yes, for sure

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            // do some actions here, for example
            // print first column value from selected row
            System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid this is not what I need because when valueChanged() is fired, the new selected row has already been set, independently the user clicked yes or now in the JOptionPane. Instead, I need it waits

Comment: ahh, sr about my missunderstanding, you should add a TableModelListener as described https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange.
also, in your listener once you've updated the value of the other cell values programatically you will need to call model.fireTableCellUpdated to let swing know about the changes
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

> when the user clicks into another row,

What about when the user used the up/down arrow keys to move to another row?

The default behaviour in both cases is to select the row automatically.

You might be able to override the `changeSelection(...)` method of the JTable. I believe this is the method that is invoked by the mouse or keyboard logic to change row selection.

So you would add your logic to display the option pane and then if "Yes" is selected you would invoke `super.changeSelection(...)`.

However, I would find it frustrating to try and use the keyboard to scroll down the table if this option pane keeps popping up. Remember to design a user interface that support both mouse and keyboard effectively.